# Get kwargs passed to url_for in Flask view

Tags: python, flask

I am passing some kwargs to `url_for`, but `**kwargs` in the view function isn't getting them.  How do I get the extra data?

#### File `admin.py`

```
@admin_bp.route('/alerts', methods=['GET'])
def display_alerts(**kwargs):
    print kwargs
    alert_sorted = Alert.query.filter_by(**kwargs).all()
```

```html
index.html
<a href="{{ url_for('admin.display_alerts', {'user_id':val.user_id} )}}">Show User Alerts</a>
```

#### File `models.py`

```
class Alert(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'alert'
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}

    alert_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.BigInteger, db.ForeignKey('users.user_id'), nullable=False)
    name = db.Column(db.String(ALERT_NAME_MAX_SIZE), nullable=False)
```

I cannot modify the function `display_alerts(**kwargs)` because it is used by a lot of other functions. My issue is to understand how to send `kwargs` arguments into the `url_for()` function in HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `request.args`. Any unknown keywords arguments passed to `url_for` will be used to populate the query string. The query string is then exposed through `request.args`.

```
@admin_bp.route('/alerts')
@admin_auth
def display_alerts():
    print(request.args)
```