# How to use kwargs in Flask's url_for method

Tags: python, flask

I have a certain method `methodA` that I need to add optional arguments to in Flask. This is typically trivial with the use of `**kwargs` --

```
@subapp.route('endpoint',methods=['GET','POST'])
def methodA(required_arg,**kwargs):
    #stuff
```

But my problem arises when I try and invoke `**kwargs` using `url_for()` in the template. In `django`, something like this would work just fine --

```
<a href = "{{url_for('subapp.methodA',required_arg='arg',kwargs={'additional_arg':'arg'})}}">A Link</a>
```

When I try that in Flask, it simply interprets the `kwargs={'additional_arg':'arg'}` as raw text and escapes everything, ignoring the variable in the process. This same exact question [was asked earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38704629/get-kwargs-passed-to-url-for-in-flask-view). However, omitting the `kwargs=` part as the OP did, something like

```
<a href = "{{url_for('subapp.methodA',required_arg='arg', {'additional_arg':'arg'})}}">A Link</a>
```

gives me a `TemplateSyntaxError`, specifically

```
TemplateSyntaxError: invalid syntax for function call expression
```

Additionally, the older question's accepted answer doesn't explain how to properly add the additional arguments in `url_for`. Consequently, `request.args` fails to capture the arguments in `kwargs`. Even if `kwargs=` remains in `url_for`, `request.args` *still* fails to extract the extra arguments. (To be precise, Flask doesn't even make it to the method -- it escapes `kwargs` entirely and yields a `404` error) The older question didn't have anything useful for my problem -- does anyone have any new advice as to what I should do?

Answer (score 0):

Pass the extra arguments the same way you would in Python, as `key='value'`:

```
<a href = "{{url_for('subapp.methodA', required_arg='arg', additional_arg='arg')}}">
```